# Using a JDBC Type 3 driver with Java 1.6

Tags: java, jdbc, java-6

I've read in several places that if you are using Java 1.6 then you should use type 4 JDBC drivers. Does that mean that you should *not* use type 3 drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type 4 drivers are generally much preferred, for reasons of simplicity. No native code, and no middleware.

However, other driver types are still perfectly valid, they're just more effort to set up. If you need to use them, then don't be afraid to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It probably just means that if you can, you might as well take advantage of the extra feature set provided by JDBC 4 if you are using Java 1.6...